# Best practices in achieving a great cohesion from multiple interfaces

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, interface, structure

First, sorry for imperfection in my wording, just let me know if there are unclear points.

While I am building the class structure of a java application, I wonder if there are the known best practices that I've not found yet in my case.

For example, There are A, B, C and more classes specifying device types, and each device has a tokenizer, parser, and compiler.

First, I have four interfaces like these.

```
interface Device {
    public void x();
    public int y();
    public String z();
    ...
}

interface Tokenizer {...}

interface Parser {...}

interface Compiler {...}
```

And, the actual concrete classes are,

```
public class ADevice implements Device {...}
public class BDevice implements Device {...}
public class CDevice implements Device {...}

class ATokenizer implements Tokeninzer {...}
class BTokenizer implements Tokeninzer {...}
class CTokenizer implements Tokeninzer {...}

class AParser implements Parser {...}
...

class ACompiler implements Compiler {...}
...
```

**Additionally and importantly**, the "Device" classes and its interface are public so that will be contained in a stub lib. Anything else will only be included in the actual library and not visible to users who generate scripts by referring to the API.

---

### Here is my question, (Long introduction :[ )

***How to achieve the cohesion between each type and its corresponding interfaces.***

In more detail, is there a way to determine whether they are paired right, between each type of device interface and its corresponding tokenizer, parser, or compiler interface in a compile time?

For example, there is a manager class that uses "Device" objects and "Tokenizer", "Parser", and "Compiler" objects. As you can see, "ADevice" objects can only be a pair with "ATokenizer", "AParser", or "ACompiler". However, if we define their type of the device objects from the interface, then there is no way we can tell if those objects are corresponding to the right "Tokenizer", "Parser", or "Compiler" object, except that "instanceOf" operator in a run time.
For instance, "ADevice" can be matched with "BTokenizer", "CParser", and so forth, and that will not generate the compile error.

I hope that I would like to hear a good answer or redirect to references.

Comment: How do the different device implementations differ from each other? Can you give examples?

Comment: Welcome on SO, don't worry we *do* like long introduction ! Can you explicit what A, B and C represent exactly ? I believe generics would elegantly solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to paramaterize your interfaces:

```
interface Tokenizer<D extends Device> { ... }
interface Parser<D extends Device> { ... }
interface Compiler<D extends Device> { ... }
```

Then your implementations would be:

```
class ATokenizer implements Tokeniser<ADevice> { ... }
class BTokenizer implements Tokenizer<BDevice> { ... }
class CTokenizer implements Tokenizer<CDevice> { ... }

class AParser implements Parser<ADevice> { ... }
.
.
.
class ACompiler implements Compiler<ADevice> { ... }
```

You could then have a method in your `Manager` class that restrict them to the same type:

```
public <D extends Device> void doStuff(Tokeizer<D> tokenizer, Parser<D> parser, Compiler<D> compiler) { ... }
```

The compiler would then only allow it to be used as you descibe:

```
doStuff(new ATokeizer(), new AParser(), new ACompiler()); // works

doStuff(new ATokeizer(), new AParser(), new BCompiler()); // compiler error
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about generic interfaces?

With interface like below:

```
public interface Parser<E extends Device> {
    void parse(E device);
    void parse(String someString);

}
```

You could create class like this:

```
public class AParser implements Parser<ADevice> {

    @Override
    public void parse(ADevice device) {
        //parse...
    }

    @Override
    void parse(String someString) {
        //parse...
    }

}
```